# How can I expand a Do Until IsEmpty Loop for two loops more?

Tags: excel, loops, is-empty, vba

In Excel I have a column of data. I want to use this column of data for a loop. 
The code below stops when it hits 1 empty row. However I need the loop to proceed for two steps more.

```
i = 1
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value2)
    'do something...
i = i + 1
Loop
```

In other words, is there something like:

```
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value2) + 2
```

I hope my question is clear!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a new variable to track this. You can do it in the existing `DO UNTIL` loop:

```
i = 1
extraTwo = 1
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value2) or extraTwo > 2
    'do something...
    i = i + 1
    if IsEmpty(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value2) then extraTwo = extraTwo + 1
Loop
```

Or in an outside loop:

```
i = 1
Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value2)
    'do something...
    i = i + 1
Loop

For extraTwo = 1 to 2
    'do something...
    i = i + 1
    extraTwo = extraTwo + 1
Next
```

The first one means no code duplication (even if you move `do something...` to a function or subroutine you have to duplicate the call), but the second is slightly more obvious what is happening (although that's debatable).

Answer (score 1):

You could use something on the lines of

```
Dim numEmpties as Long
i = 1       
Do While True
    If IsEmpty(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Data").Cells(i, 1).Value2) Then
        numEmpties = numEmpties + 1
        If numEmpties = 3 Then Exit Do
    End If
    'do something
    i = i + 1
Loop
```

Here I'm essentially controlling the loop indexing manually, and writing it this way is elegant insofar that the `IsEmpty` test is only written once. (This is idiomatic in C.)